# FATAL ERROR: PHP mbstring extension is not enabled (IIS8/Windows 2012)

Tags: windows, iis-8, windows-server-2012, mantis

I am facing issues while install MantisBT after installing PHP 7.2 in IIS8 / Windows 2012 server.

When I open the page `http://localhost:9099/admin/install.php` in the browser, I get the following error:

> "FATAL ERROR: PHP mbstring extension is not enabled."

Here is a screenshot of the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJiPc.jpg).

Comment: I have searched for extension=php_mbstring.dll in INI file of php7 but didn't work

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution..

> After investigate the issue the reason was php.ini file is getting recognized by server
>   Rename the .ini development or production to only .ini so that application can get the path and issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue here
I triple checked everything in regards to setting up my PHP.ini file

but there is a comment that mentions on Windows servers, you have to add a line to the config to specify the extension directory

For PHP 8 I had to add the following line to the top of the extension section

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

(also making sure to uncomment extension=exif as the detault config said it was needed)

I rebooted with the CMD command "IISReset" and my webapp that required mbstring booted up fine!